# Procedure deleterecord has no parameters and arguments were supplied

Tags: c#, sql, petapoco

I wrote a stored procedure for delete record in SQL server database
But I Can not send parameters with stored procedures.
This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteRecord]
AS
    DECLARE @id INT

    DELETE FROM Student1 WHERE id = @id
```

This is my C# code calling this stored procedure:

```
var db = new PetaPoco.Database("test");
    db.Fetch<Models.Generated.test.Student1>("; EXEC [dbo].[DeleteRecord] @@Id = @0", Id);
```

Comment: Typo? `whrere` should be `where`

Comment: I can not Exec stored procedure because i think my procedure is wrong

Comment: I answered you yesterday under a different account and question: this whole code is one big typo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67055455/call-stored-procedure-in-c-sharp-with-petapoco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your proc definition is not correct,  you are not passing any parameter to your function , that variable inside proc never gets any value (It's always null since no value has been assigned to it)

```
CREATE OR ALTER Procedure [dbo].[DeleteRecord]
( 
    @id INT
) 
AS 
Delete from Student1 where id=@id
```

Comment: Thank you very much your code is correct